# Delayed search using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with a search control for one of my project using Angular. I was trying for delayed response like the search box should wait until 2 seconds before calling the relevant function.

When I search the web, most of the suggestion was to use a directive. I cannot use directive since clicking the search result in turn shows another set of results. I got another solution after pondering over in the web.

My code:

```
<div ng-controller="ReportCtrl" ng-app="pReport">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchString"  placeholder="Search"/>
    <div ng-show="display == 'search'">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in batches">
                <a ng-click='selectBatch(i.batchnumber)'>{{i.batchnumber}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="display == 'repdetail'">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in reports">
                <a href='{{i.filename}}'>{{i.screenname}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular Expressions

```
    var app = angular.module('pReport', []);

    app.controller('ReportCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

        var timer = false;
        $scope.batches = [];
        $scope.reports = [];
        $scope.$watch('searchString', function () {

            if (timer) {
                $timeout.cancel(timer);
            }
            timer = $timeout(function () {

                $http({ }). //POSTING DETAILS
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {}); //SEARCH RESULTS
            }, 1000)
        });
        $scope.selectBatch = function (batchNumber) { } // SEARCH FURTHER
    });
```

1. Is there anything wrong in this approach of delaying?
2. Should I use a directive?
3. Is there any other most efficient approach?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The better way is to use a directive. Since you are not interested in that approach this will be fine. Nothing wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `debounce`. [Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) provide this capability out of the box. The good news is Angular is getting this functionality in an upcoming version [built-in](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2129#issuecomment-17444687).

It prevent execution of a function more than once per given time period. This is ideal for situations like a typeahead search box where you'd like to wait before firing off another request to the server and event handling in general.

In this case, I'd remove the watch and the move the `$http` call to its own function wrapped in a debounce:

```
$scope.search = function() {
    _.debounce($http(...), 1000, { leading: false, trailing: true })
}
```

The `leading` and `trailing` just configure when the debounce will occur, in our case, we want it to happen after the initial 1000 wait.

And then change the input box to use `ng-change` so it triggers the function when a user types in something, but only once every 1000ms:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchString"  placeholder="Search" ng-change="search()"/>
```